# reading column from excel and doing specific math

Tags: python, excel, testing

I have an excel file that has 27 columns. I want to write a python code which reads column by column and stores the final 5 values in the coloum which will have math equations done on them.

I have this so far:

```
from math import tan

#Write Header
#outFile.write('Test Name,X+ avg,X+ std,X+ count,X- avg,X- std,X- count,X angle,Y+ avg,Y+ std,Y+ count,Y- avg,Y- std,Y- count,Y angle\n')

#for line in inFile:


if 1==1:

    line = [1,2,38.702,37.867,35.821, 44, 49,55,65,20,25,28,89.]

    line0= len(line)
    print "the list size"
    print line0

    line1 = len(line) -5  #takes the overall line and subtracts 5. 
    print "the is the start of the 5 #'s we need"
    print line1 #prints the line

    d= line[line1:line0]       #pops all the values from in the line (..)
    print "these are the 5 #'s we need"
    print d

    lo=min(d)
    hi=max(d)


    print "the lowest value is"
    print lo


    print "the highest value is"
    print hi

    average1 = float (sum(d))/ len(d)   #sum
    print "the average of the values is"
    print average1
```

the "line = [1,2,38.702,37.867,35.821, 44, 49,55,65,20,25,28,89.]" part I want python to automatically read in the coloumn, store the 5 last vales and  do the above math analysis.

Comment: For the last five items of a list named `line` do `line[-5:]`.  Now, this Excel file, is it truly an Excel file or is it a csv?  If Excel, is it a .xls or .xlsx?  Is it the opening the Excel file that's the problem, or is the problem extracting the last five values from a row?

Comment: Well, no, because i want python the retrive the column, and store the last 5 characters and then apply these math on it. Like i stated, that "line = [1,2,38.702,37.867,35.821, 44, 49,55,65,20,25,28,89.]" was just to see that my equations were working. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to use a library like [openpyxl](http://packages.python.org/openpyxl/), here's an example from the docs on how to access certain cells.

```
columnOffset = 2 # column offset is (the letter as a number - 1), a = (1-1), b = (2-1)
rowOffset = 35 # row offset is row number - 1

wb = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
ws = wb.get_active_sheet()
for column in ws.columns[columnOffset:27]: #because you have 27 columns to parse through
    for rowIndex, cell in enumerate(column[-5:]):
        if rowIndex >= rowOffset:
            print cell.value
```

Unfortunately openpyxl doesn't have really good support for columns so you'll have to use indexes to get your columns.

**Based on xlrd**

```
import xlrd

wb = xlrd.open_workbook("C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\herp.xls")
sh = wb.sheet_by_name(u'A Snazzy Title')

for index in xrange(2, 4):
    lastFive = sh.col_values(index, start_rowx=59, end_rowx=64)
    print lastFive
```

It looks like xlrd treats the entire spreadsheet like a 2D list, so remember to start your indexes at 0. Yes xlrd is based entirely in python.

*credit to [alexis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/699305/alexis) for pointing out this module.*

Comment: how about something along these lines without having to download libararies to read the data?

inFile = open("input_test.csv", "r")
outFile = open("results.txt", "w")

for line in inFile:

Comment: @user1778360, I don't believe python has built-in support for excel, which is unfortunate for you.

Comment: okay so if I was able to download openpyxl, how can I keep it looping in the column until it reaches the last 5 numbers and then prints them out?

Comment: Thank you johnthexii.. I do have just 2 more questions, 

1. does openpyxl work on 64 bit window 7
2. I have 27 columns so how would that work to keep it going through all 27 and retrieving the last 5 values

Comment: @user1778360, openpyxl is written purely in python, so it will work on any system that runs python. For the second question, are those twenty-seven columns the only columns in the worksheet?

Comment: oh nice. So this means I don"t have to download anything for openpyxl?. I am acually new to python so i appologize if I am making things too hards. And for the second question, no there is other stuff on the work sheet however I need it to start in coloumn C and row 36.  and then column D row 36...  and so on. thanks

Comment: hi johnthexii.. thanks for your hepo. does the second script need openpyx. Because am running 64 bit window 7 and so hard to download it. Thanks

Comment: @user1778360, no the second script is based on a different module, xlrd, it is compatible with win7 64bit.

Comment: I have installed "xlrd 0.8.0". Its basically multiple .py files. how do I install it so that it allows the script to execute?

Answer (score 0):

FYI there's also `xlrd`/`xlwt`, from the python-excel project ( http://www.python-excel.org/ ). You also need to download it, though. I've never used  openpyxl so I can't say which one is better.

Comment: I've heard of xlrd/xlwt, it looks like that combination has quite a bit more functionality than openpyxl.